# Consulta em tabela com auto-relacionamento

Tags: mysql, sql

Possuo a seguinte tabela contendo auto-relacionamento entre as colunas idcategoria e pai:

```
idcategoria categoria   pai
1           Camisetas   0
2           Regata      1
```

Quando uma categoria adicionada não possuir uma categoria pai o valor da coluna será zero, e caso contrário a coluna pai possuirá o valor da idcategoria da sua categoria pai correspondente.
Tentei da seguinte forma, mas não deu certo pelo fato da coluna pai por vezes ser zero, o que forçaria a exibição de somente valores com categorias pai.
Segue:

```
SELECT c.*, p.categoria AS catpai FROM categoria AS c, categoria AS p WHERE p.pai = c.idcategoria;
```

A intenção é pegar como resultado todas as categorias e o nome das categorias PAI das que possuírem categoria pai. Só trabalharei com dois níveis.

Comment: Você quer pegar somente dois níveis?

Comment: É vero, corrigido.

Comment: Exato, preciso de todas as categorias e na saída o nome das categorias PAI. No entanto só trabalharei com dois níveis.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Se quiser todas as categorias, me parece o caso de usar LEFT JOIN:

```
SELECT
   c.*,
   p.categoria AS catpai
FROM
   categoria AS c
LEFT JOIN
   categoria AS p ON c.pai = p.idcategoria;
```

Notar que usei `c.pai = p.categoria`, e não o inverso como na sua original.

Veja mais sobre JOINs **[neste link](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/6441)**.

Comment: É isso mesmo, eu realmente não me lembrava mais como funcionada os JOINs. Muito Obrigado.

Answer (score 3):

Olha se é isto que você precisa:

```
SELECT 
  c.*, p.categoria AS catpai 
FROM 
  categoria AS c
  left join categoria AS p on p.pai = c.idcategoria;
```